# I created a plot with plotly on a Jupyter Notebook but when I download it as an html file, the plot appears blank, what should I do?

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I used plotly to create an interactive timeline of my data on a Jupyter Notebook. The plot on the notebook looks perfect and works just fine, however, when I download the notebook as an html file, I can't see the plot.

I will not share the original data frame for privacy reasons and because it isn't really relevant.

Here's the code I used to make the graph:

```
#Interactive Line Plot
import plotly 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(df.Date), y=list(df.Transactions), marker=dict(size=20, color="blue")))

#Set title
fig.update_layout(title_text="Total Number of Transactions per Date", title_font_size=20)

#Add range slider
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

In the Jupyter notebook I get a plot that looks like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HyT7.png)

But when I download the notebook as an html file the plot is blank, it doesn't appear. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: it may generate plot as JavaScript object which needs to run JavaScript to generate it again to display it again. When you save it as HTML then it may not have access to JavaScript without access to full server. Check if it can generate png image.

Comment: pls try to add `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)` just  after all of your import statements. And then when you again download as .HTML, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if you want plotly figures to be downloadable from Jupyter notebook, you do:

```
fig.show(renderer='notebook')
```